# SharePoint: There is no Web named error when retrieving lists

Tags: sharepoint

I am working in sharepoint server 2010. My requirement is to access the all the lists from the current site.

In my sharepoint server I have these things below:
1) Sitecollection which contains sub-sites

Ex: http://servername:portNo/SiteA/default.aspx where SiteA is subsite.

2)WebApplication and sites under it.

Ex: http://servername:portNo/sites/ProjectA/default.aspx where ProjectA is a site under the webapplication

Now I need to get all the lists which is present in the current site for which I am using below code

```
SPSite SiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWeb web = SiteCollection.AllWebs[CurrentSiteAddress];            
List<SPList> listCollection = new List<SPList>();
SPListCollection **lists** = web.Lists;
```

The above code works when the current site is a sitecollection i.e main site and its sub-sites. However the code breaks when my current site is a site under web-application.

Exception Message: There is no Web named \"/sites/ProjectA\"."

But when debug below code,

> SPListCollection **lists** = web.Lists;

**lists** collection does not get populated. But after some delay **lists** collection gets populated and works without any problem. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this? and How can I resolver this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string siteurl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
string weburl = SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;

using (SPWeb safeWeb = new SPSite(siteurl).OpenWeb(weburl))
{
    SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
    foreach (SPList list in lists)
    {
      //do whatever you want with your list(s)
    }
}
```